# Xamarin multiplatform - Video from jpeg sequence

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, windows-phone, mjpeg

I want to know how I can display video from jpegs in Xamarin (all platforms).

My jpegs are being streamed from a http client stream sent by a popular video surveillance management software.

My jpegs are in the form of **byte[]** and I get about **10 jpegs/second**. This format is imposed.

I tried rapidly changing the **Source** on a **Image** but it results in severe fliquering on Android. This seems to work on Windows phone but not so good performance.

How can I create a videoplayer for each one? Unless I am wrond, the existing components cannot do this.

Best,

Comment: You might try displaying them with SkiaSharp, which would allow you to draw on an offscreen canvas and then display the image, which might help with the flickering

Comment: Have you tested on other platform? Only on android device will it flick?

Comment: Grace, I tested on Windows phone it was fine. Did not test on IOS, but there is a good chance it will not flicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Jason! Works great, very fluid rendering!!

Simply add the SkiaSharp.Views.Forms with NuGet to the project and voila!

Here is what that would look like in code (shared project):

```
// Content page initialization
private void InitUI() {

    Title = "Xamavideo";

    var button = new Button
    {
        Text = "Connect!"
    };
    Label label = new Label
    {
        Text = ""
    };

    var scroll = new ScrollView();
    scroll.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
    Content = scroll;
    var stack = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = 40,
        Spacing = 10
    };

    //Add a SKCanvasView item to the stack
    var videoCanvas = new SKCanvasView
    {                
        HeightRequest = 400,
        WidthRequest = 600,                
    };
    videoCanvas.PaintSurface += OnCanvasViewPaintSurface;
    stack.Children.Add(videoCanvas);
}

//Create the event handler
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;            

    // using (var stream = new SKManagedStream(fileStream))
    if (lastFrame == null) return;
    using (var canvas = surface.Canvas)
    // use KBitmap.Decode to decode the byte[] in jpeg format 
    using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(lastFrame))
    using (var paint = new SKPaint())
    {
        // clear the canvas / fill with black
        canvas.DrawColor(SKColors.Black);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, SKRect.Create(640, 480), paint);
    }
}

void UpdateFrame(VideoClient client){

   //Use this to update the canvas:
   byte[] lastFrame = client.imageBytes;
   videoCanvas.InvalidateSurface();                                   
}
```